# Efficient self-referencing 0..1 to 0..1 relationship

Tags: mysql, self-reference, one-to-zero-or-one

What is the best practice for such a relationship in regards to data consistency and performance?

My first instinct was to add a new self-referencing column:

```
ALTER TABLE Edata_auction
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS extendedWith INT UNSIGNED;
ALTER TABLE Edata_auction
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_extended_id FOREIGN KEY IF NOT EXISTS
          (extendedWith) REFERENCES Edata_auction(id);
```

But then after some thinking I can see two immediate issues with it:

- this is practically a many to 1 relationship, not 0..1 to 0..1
- I will need to check if any loan has links to it (both in `WHERE` and in PHP code) - do I need to add another index for `extendedWith`? Every index has a cost, and almost all loans will have no self-links, so maybe there's a better way?

Should I instead create another table with a complex primary key of `(extended_loan_id, extending_loan_id)`? Would it be fast to join/filter/search *separately* by `extended_loan_id` and `extending_loan_id`, i.e. when only one id is specified?

FWIW the business logic behind this relationship is this: a loan can be extended with a new loan. So any loan can have no related extensions, can be extended with another loan, can be itself an extension of another loan, or both.

Comment: 1:(0..1) is `slave ( column NULL UNIQUE ) REFERENCES main ( column NOT NULL UNIQUE )`.

Comment: @Akina it's not 1:(0..1), it's (0..1):(0..1). And many 'slaves' must allow null main.

Comment: *it's (0..1):(0..1)* ??? I don't understand this "scheme". My code allows either 0:1 or 1:1 relation and does not allow 1:0 (slave value must refer to existing main value, and the column in main is defined as NOT NULL). 0:0 makes no sense at all.

Comment: Eh?  A measurement referencing an id?

Comment: To discuss `INDEXes`, we need to se the queries that might use such indexes.

Answer (score 0):

> a loan can be extended with a new loan. So any loan can have no related extensions, can be extended with another loan, can be itself an extension of another loan, or both.

```
CREATE TABLE loans (
  loan_id INT PRIMARY KEY,   -- unique loan identifier
  amount DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,  -- loan sum
  extends_id INT UNIQUE,  -- if it extends previous loan then stores its ID
                          -- else stores NULL
  FOREIGN KEY (extends_id) REFERENCES loans (loan_id),  -- relation between extending loan
                                                   -- and extended loan
  CHECK (amount > 0)  -- check that the loan sum is positive
);
```

```
INSERT INTO loans VALUES (100, 123.45, NULL);
-- root loan
```

```
INSERT INTO loans VALUES (200, 234.56, NULL);
-- another root loan
```

```
INSERT INTO loans VALUES (300, 345.67, 100);
-- extend loan 100
```

```
INSERT INTO loans VALUES (400, 456.78, 300);
-- extend loan 300 which extends loan 100
```

```
INSERT INTO loans VALUES (500, 567.89, 100);
-- extend loan 100 one more time - fail
```

> ```
> Duplicate entry '100' for key 'loans.extends_id'
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Of_GmAtq)

Comment: this will allow multiple loan records have the same non-null `extends_id`, which is what looks like many-to-one to me

Comment: @AntonDuzenko Watch carefully! `extends_id` is defined as **UNIQUE**, so multiple loans which extends the same loan cannot exist.

Comment: What about performance when searching for a row with a given `extends_id`? Does it need another index for that?